# Vue: v-for not rendering (using Node and Axios)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, crud, v-for

I'm trying to fetch some data from my MySql DB in the table 'clients' (to make a CRUD later on), but nothing is rendered when I try to output in a v-for. The 'ul' is rendered but its empty because the 'li's is not rendered. I don't get any error, its just not rendering?

My code is here:

Router.js (server-side):

```
// routes/router.js

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const uuid = require('uuid');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const db = require('../lib/db.js');
const userMiddleware = require('../middleware/users.js');

// (Working) code for a login - removed here to make it more simple
// (Working) code for a login - removed here to make it more simple
// (Working) code for a login - removed here to make it more simple

router.get('/clients', (req, res, next) => {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM clients", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send();
            throw err;
        }

        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(result);
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

My Clients.vue (client-side):

```
<template>
  <div>

      Hi {{ username | capitalize }}

      <ul>
        <li :key="client.id" v-for="client in clients">
          <strong>{{ client.name }}</strong>
          <small>{{ client.email }}</small> | <small>{{  client.phone }}</small>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" @click="logout">Logout</a>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AuthService from '@/services/AuthService.js';
  import ClientService from '@/services/ClientService.js';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        secretMessage: 'Sample secret message',
        username: '',
        clients: []
      };
    },

    async created() {
      if (!this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
        this.$router.push('/login');
      }
      this.username = this.$store.getters.getUser.username;
      this.secretMessage = await AuthService.getSecretContent();

      var self = this
      ClientService.getClients().then((clients) => {
        self.clients = clients;
      });

    },
    methods: {
      logout() {
        this.$store.dispatch('logout');
        this.$router.push('/login');
      }
    },
    filters: {
      capitalize: function (value) {
        if (!value) return ''
        value = value.toString()
        return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
      }
    },
  };

</script>
```

And my ClientService.js looks like this:

```
// src/services/ClientService.js

import axios from 'axios';
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';
export default {
    getClients() {
        return axios
            .get(url + 'clients/')
            .then(response => response.data);
    }
};
```

When I run the get request for 'http://localhost:3000/api/clients' in Postman I receive the correct data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sample Client One",
        "email": "email-one@domain.com",
        "phone": "12345678"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Sample Client two",
        "email": "mail-two@domain.com",
        "phone": "12345678"
    }
]
```

What am i doing wrong?

//Rue

Comment: Hello! Did you try to omit the 'async' from the created method? Otherwise try to put a console.log(self.clients) after you assign the value to it, in the .then() function of the ClientService call.

Comment: Did you checked F12 on the network tab if you receive a response with data

Comment: It worked to remove the 'async' (and the 'await') - I just though they were important for login. what does it async do?

Comment: hmm the secretMessage (secretMessage: 'Sample secret message',) doesn't work any more - it just returns '[object Promise]'? Can I have a async created AND a created at the same time?

Comment: @Rue I've added the explanation to your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the `async` from `async created()` will fix the issue.

You can read more about async functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await). The important part for your issue is that the created method, on the Vue component, is not supposed to return a Promise.

Answer (score -1):

The function `created` is synchronous.  In the documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created the details section reveals:

> Called synchronously after the instance is created